# Multiple case with different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query like this:

```
select U.Name,U.Adluserid as 'Empid', 
       min(case when IOType=0 then Edatetime end) as 'IN',
       max(case when IOType=1 then Edatetime end) as 'out'
       from Mx_ACSEventTrn
inner join Mx_UserMst U on Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode=U.UserID
left join Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus E on  Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode=E.Emp_Id
where cast(Edatetime as date) between '2019-10-30' and '2019-10-30' 
group by U.Name,U.Adluserid
```

**output**

```
 Name            Empid     IN                          OUT                status           
JAS             505  2019-10-30 08:06:37.000    2019-10-30 14:13:29.000   Present
SAAJ            516  2019-10-30 08:05:11.000    2019-10-30 14:17:58.000   Absent
ram             516  2019-10-30 08:20:11.000    2019-10-30 14:17:58.000   Late
```

I have a another table like this: Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus

```
Emp_Id  Status
123      2
504      2
505      3
```

- I want to show the status column depend on this condition. If IN time
  is not null then check the time more than 8.15 AM. If it is more than
  8.15 AM then show late other wise show present.
- IF in time is null then check the status of employee from this
  table "Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus", if status 2 then show "Absent" if status 3
  then show "Vacation" like this.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Why is SAAJ's status Absent? His in time is not null. According to your logic, he should be Present. **Also**, which database is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an additional query level (sub-select) to be able to operate on `in` and `out` time which are aggregates (min and max). To be able to join your data with `Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus` we need to provide outer query with `u.UserID` and then perform a left join based on that column.

Final query just needs a `CASE` expression to evaluate your conditions and set expected status based on `in` time column.

```
select
  t.Name,
  t.Empid,
  t.t_in,
  t.t_out,
  case 
    when t.t_in is null and E.status = 2 then 'Absent'
    when t.t_in is null and E.status = 3 then 'Vacation'
    when cast(t.t_in as time) > '08:15' then 'Late' else 'Present' 
    end as status
from (
  select 
    u.UserID,
    u.Name,
    u.Adluserid as empid, 
    min(case when IOType=0 then Edatetime end) as t_in,
    max(case when IOType=1 then Edatetime end) as t_out,
  from 
    Mx_ACSEventTrn t
    inner join Mx_UserMst u on t.UsrRefcode = u.UserID
  where 
    cast(Edatetime as date) between '2019-10-30' and '2019-10-30' 
  group by 
    u.UserId, u.Name, u.Adluserid
) t
left join Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus e on t.UserID = e.Emp_Id
```

Comment: shwoing error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: Try now. IN is a reserved keyword and so is OUT. This is why you shouldn't be using them. I've replaced them with t_in and t_out. Finally we know this is SQL Server :)

Comment: it is working perfect,thanks,but i have small query

Comment: i want to add a condition like if IN time is null i want to look for another table and show the status.that case how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid inner select like this

```
select 
    u.UserID,
    u.Name,
    u.Adluserid as empid, 
    min(case when IOType=0 then Edatetime end) as t_in,
    max(case when IOType=1 then Edatetime end) as t_out
    into #tmp 
from 
    Mx_ACSEventTrn t
    inner join Mx_UserMst u on t.UsrRefcode = u.UserID
where 
    cast(Edatetime as date) between '2019-10-30' and '2019-10-30' 
group by 
u.UserId, u.Name, u.Adluserid

select
  t.Name,
  t.Empid,
  t.t_in,
  t.t_out,
  case 
    when t.t_in is null and E.status = 2 then 'Absent'
    when t.t_in is null and E.status = 3 then 'Vacation'
    when cast(t.t_in as time) > '08:15' then 'Late' else 'Present' 
    end as status
from 
#tmp t
left join Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus e on t.UserID = e.Emp_Id
```